# How can I pull out the ID from this string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using the TableDnD jQuery plugin to make a table row sortable (http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/).  Using FireFox, I used `console.log(row)` to see what the value for row was `onDrop`.  In doing so, Firefox spit out this:

```
<tr id="row_2" class="" valign="top" style="cursor: move;">
```

How can I pull out the id from this string, or more importantly, I really just need the number (2 in this example) when the row is dropped.  The ultimate goal is so I can show a message to the user that the sorting has been updated and I'd prefer to not use an alert box because then the user has to dismiss it for each item dropped.

Comment: i'd expect `row.id` or `$(row).id` to work. then you only need to extract the number (either with a regular expression or with substring)

Comment: This seems to work.  Can anyone see any problem with this?
`var $tr = $(row);    
var row_id = $tr.attr("id");    
var id = row_id.split("_");    
console.log(id[1]);`

Comment: I have created a jsFiddle demonstrating the validity of the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/JspRR/1/ Please see my reply for an answer that uses this technique. It is very general, safe and quite handy :-) It works both when you have a DOM item or the HTML for that DOM item, thanks to jQuery :-)

Comment: Thanks for trying my answer and verifying it works.  Please remember to accept if it served its purpose :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the html for the row (or the actual DOM row object) in a varable called tr:

```
var id = $(tr).attr("id")
```

Please also visit the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JspRR/1/

Comment: @dlackey: Glad I was able to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `data-`-prefixed [HTML5 attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes):

```html
<tr data-id="2"></tr>
```

And then access it with `getAttribute()`:

```js
var id = tr.getAttribute('data-id');
```

Comment: Hmmm.. I have to admit, I keep forgetting about data attributes.  I'll plug this into my code and see if it works.  I'll give you an up vote for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do something like:

```
row.id.match(/\d+$/)[0]
```